# I bought app when it was paid, now it is free and I have to watch ads

Tags: google-play-store, ads, paid-apps

I bought game a few years ago. I performed factory reset on android tablet because it was slow. Installed game after some time. Now I see ads. But I paid for that app? What can I do to get add free version? Or can I get refund?

Comment: A reboot does not change anything on the installed apps. Most likely you mean that you reinstalled your tablet (factory reset + reinstall), right?

Comment: @Robert  Right :-)

Comment: Are you sure you installed the exact same game app? The PlayStore name may change over the time. Use the "collection" app list in PlayStore which contains all apps you had ever installed.

Comment: If it is a popular app there are lots of sites on Google that displays past app downloads/versions.  Try "app name apk"

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps**

1. Contact the app developer if they are not able to resolve your problem follow other steps.
2. Use Net Guard app or any other network blocker app to block that app's internet access.
3. Use LuckyPatcher and remove google ads package (before you try this step I tell you in 3 option google-play-store give you warning to remove the lucky patcher app). Try 3 option at your own risk.

Comment: If you are going to recommend Lucky Patcher to anyone, you should let them know that it is pirating software, and is not supported by any respectable developer... In most legitimate developer circles, anyone using Lucky Patcher is labeled a thief as the software has little other use.

Answer (score 0):

Their might have been an ad supported version released after you purchased the Paid version, Usually looking through your purchased apps on the PlayStore you'll find the Paid version to download again.   I use [My Paid Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jkg.mypaidapps) to reinstall any of my purchases.